# Identityserver3 getting accesstoken in a implicit flow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, access-token, identityserver3

We have a MVC client with impicit flow, and CookieAuthentication. Now we would like to call another api (same STS) from javascript, so we need an accesstoken.

Question: How do we get the accesstoken. This is our mvc client setup:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            CookieName = "AuthCookieCoolApp",

        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"],
            ClientId = "CoolApp",
            RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"],
            ResponseType = "id_token token", // added token here
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            Scope = "cool_profile openid profile",
        }
```

Using fiddler we see that the accesstoken is posted from Identityserver back to the redirceturi, but how can we grab it? We found the `Notifications`property on the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions`, but none of the event seems to fit.

Bonus question: When we get the accesstoken on the server (mvc), whats the perferd way of sending it to the browser? Store it on server, and send it on every page that might need to call the new api, or requesting it from javascript when needed?

Thanks for any guidance

Larsi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the access token from the Protocol Message like:

```
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                MessageReceived = notification =>
                {
                    var message = notification.ProtocolMessage;
                    var accesstoken = message.AccessToken;
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
```